# Custom fonts only works the first time QML

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, symbian, qml

I am really struggling with this and not sure how to solve this issue.

Here is the code.

**I am running this on symbian ^3 (belle)**

**I have 2 custom fonts that i need to use.**

```
In the example below i have created 3 buttons.
1. Display gurbaniwebthick.ttf
2. Display GurHindi.ttf.
3. Quit.
```

**This works on N9**

I click on the first button and then click on text filed it displays the first line in Pubjabi.

Click on the second button and then click on the text filed it displays the first line in Hindi.

**When i quit the app and then run the app again the fonts are not applied. Its like it can’t get a lock on the file.**

**Please advise how to solve this issue.**

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1
Rectangle {
width: 360
height: 640
property string displaystr
property string displaystr1

FontLoader { id: localGurFont; source: "qrc:/gurbaniwebthick.ttf"}
FontLoader { id: localHinFont; source: "qrc:/Gurhindi.ttf"}
Column {
    ButtonColumn {
        checkedButton: b1
        spacing: 5
        Button{
            id:b1
            text:"<> siq nwmu krqw purKu"
            font.family: localGurFont.name
            //font.family: "Gurmukhi";
            onClicked: {
                displaystr1 =  '<font face= "'+localGurFont.name+'" size="6" color="black">kYsI AwrqI hoie Bv KMfnw qyrI AwrqI ]</font><br><br><font face= "Ariel" size="5" color="red">What A Beautiful Lamp-Lit Worship Service This Is! O Destroyer Of Fear, This Is Your Aartee, You r Worship Service.</font><br><br><font face= "Ariel" size="5" color="blue">Kehsi Aarti Hoee Bhv Khandna Teyri Aarti |</font>';
                console.log(displaystr);
            }
        }
        Button{
            id:b6
            text:"< siq nwmu krqw purKu"
            font.family: localHinFont.name
            onClicked: {

                displaystr1 = '<font face= "'+localHinFont.name+'" size="6" color="black">kYsI AwrqI hoie Bv KMfnw qyrI AwrqI ]</font><br><br><font face= "Ariel" size="5" color="red">What A Beautiful Lamp-Lit Worship Service This Is! O Destroyer Of Fear, This Is Your Aartee, You r Worship Service.</font><br><br><font face= "Ariel" size="5" color="blue">Kehsi Aarti Hoee Bhv Khandna Teyri Aarti |</font>';
                console.log(displaystr);

            }
        }

        Button{
            id:b7
            text:"Quit"
            onClicked: {
                Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
    TextArea {
        id: t1
        width: 360
        height: 360
        text: displaystr
        wrapMode:Text.WordWrap

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                displaystr = displaystr1;
                console.log(displaystr1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Same problem with the List View as well**
    // import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
   import QtQuick 1.1
   import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

```
Rectangle {
id: initialRect
height: 640
width: 360
property string fontName
// color: "black"
FontLoader { id: localGurFont; source: "qrc:/gurbaniwebthick.ttf"}
FontLoader { id: localHinFont; source: "qrc:/Gurhindi.ttf"}
    ListModel {
        id: contactModel
        ListElement {
            baani: 'kYsI AwrqI hoie Bv KMfnw qyrI AwrqI ]'
            displayColor: 'black'
            displayfont: 'GurbaniWebThick'
        }
        ListElement {
            baani: 'What A Beautiful Lamp-Lit Worship Service This Is! O Destroyer Of Fear, This Is Your Aartee,ou r Worship Service.'
            displayColor: 'red'
            displayfont: 'Arial'
        }
        ListElement {
            baani: 'Kehsi Aarti Hoee Bhv Khandna Teyri Aarti |'
            displayColor: 'blue'
            displayfont: 'Arial'
        }
        ListElement {
            baani: 'kYsI AwrqI hoie Bv KMfnw qyrI AwrqI ]'
            displayColor: 'black'
            displayfont: 'GurbaniWebThick'
        }
        ListElement {
            baani: 'What A Beautiful Lamp-Lit Worship Service This Is! O Destroyer Of Fear, This Is Your Aartee,ou r Worship Service.'
            displayColor: 'red'
            displayfont: 'Arial'
        }
        ListElement {
            baani: 'Kehsi Aarti Hoee Bhv Khandna Teyri Aarti |'
            displayColor: 'blue'
            displayfont: 'Arial'
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: baaniDelegate
        Item {
            width: parent.width ; height:parent.height/contactModel.count
            Text {
                width: parent.width
                text: baani
                font.family: displayfont
                color: displayColor
                wrapMode:  Text.WordWrap
            }
        }
    }


    ListView{

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contactModel
        delegate: baaniDelegate
        // highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius:5}
        // focus: true
    }
                Button{
                    id:b7
                    text:"Quit"
                    onClicked: {
                        Qt.quit();
                        localHinFont.deleteLater;
                        localGurFont.deleteLater;
                        localGurFont.Null;
                        localHinFont.Null;
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

**SymbianFontLoader.h**

```
#ifndef SYMBIANFONTLOADER_H
#define SYMBIANFONTLOADER_H

#include <QString>
#include <coemain.h>
#include <w32std.h>
#include <badesca.h>
#include <gulutil.h>


class SymbianFontLoader
{
public:
    SymbianFontLoader(bool retainFonts = false) {

        m_retainFonts = retainFonts;
        m_screenDevice = CCoeEnv::Static()->ScreenDevice();


    }

    ~SymbianFontLoader() {

        if (!m_retainFonts)
            foreach(int id, m_fontIds)
                m_screenDevice->RemoveFile(id);
    }

    QStringList loadedFonts() {

        QStringList fonts;
        TRAPD(err, listFontsL(fonts));

        qt_symbian_throwIfError(err);
        return fonts;
    }

    void load(QString  path) {


        qDebug() <<";"<<path<<";";
        TPtrC fontFile(path.utf16(), path.length());
        //    TPtrC fontFile(qt_QString2TPtrC(path));
        //TPtrC fontFile(path, path.length());
        qDebug()<<"path" << path.utf16() << "length" <<path.length();


        int fontId;
        int err = m_screenDevice->AddFile(fontFile, fontId);
        qDebug() <<err;

        qt_symbian_throwIfError(err);
        qDebug() <<  "after error";
        if (!m_retainFonts)
            m_fontIds << fontId;

    }

private:

    void listFontsL(QStringList& fonts) {

        CDesCArrayFlat *fontNames = new (ELeave) CDesCArrayFlat(5);

        CleanupStack::PushL(fontNames);

        FontUtils::GetAvailableFontsL(*m_screenDevice, *fontNames, EGulAllFonts);

        int fontCount = fontNames->Length();

        for (int i=0; i < fontCount; i++) {

            TPtrC fontName = fontNames->MdcaPoint(i);

            QString font = QString::fromUtf16(fontName.Ptr(), fontName.Length());

            fonts << font;
        }
        CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();
    }

private:
    CWsScreenDevice* m_screenDevice;
    bool m_retainFonts;

    QList<int> m_fontIds;
};

#endif // SYMBIANFONTLOADER_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#ifdef Q_OS_SYMBIAN
    SymbianFontLoader fontLoader(true);

    fontLoader.load("C:\\data\\2006126c\\gurbaniwebthick.ttf");

    fontLoader.load("C:\\data\\2006126c\\Gurhindi.ttf");

#endif
```

Make sure you restart the phone.

**.pro file**

```
LIBS += -lcone -lws32 -lbafl -legul

font_files.pkg_postrules += “\“C:\\QTproj\\QTDeploy\\gurbaniwebthick.ttf\” – \“C:\\data\\2006126c\\gurbaniwebthick.ttf\”“
font_files.pkg_postrules += “\“C:\\QTproj\\QTDeploy\\Gurhindi.ttf\” – \“C:\\data\\2006126c\\Gurhindi.ttf\”“

DEPLOYMENT += font_files my_deployment
```